# Sending results from a class to other class

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How can i send results from a class to other class, the results it from my mysql results. 
example first class it databaseConnection and i want to send the result from select method to other class.

Here my code:

```
Dim data As ArrayList
Public Function selectAll() As ArrayList

    Dim mySelectQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM users"
    Dim myConnection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection)
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader

    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
    ' Always call Read before accessing data.

    data = myReader



    ' always call Close when done reading.
    myReader.Close()
    ' Close the connection when done with it.
    myConnection.Close()

End Function
```

i updated a code to look  more clear
and receiver Method look like this.

```
Private Sub home_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    db = New db()
    Dim r = db.selectAll()
    MsgBox("It work" & db.selectAll().ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: There are exactly 4,472,891 ways of implementing this. What's your code looking like?

Comment: @Mat's Mug i just updated my code

Comment: This is VB.NET, not VBA.

Comment: @Matteo NNZ I'm new to this language, can you explain me please.

Comment: It means that you have used the tag for the language called [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications), but you are developing in a different language which is called [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET). I have changed your tag accordingly so it will get the attention of VB.NET developers (and not VBA developers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this numerous ways.

However, i would probably output the results to a variable in the first function. Then simply access the variable as needed from the second.

Example:

in first method:

```
   Dim list As New List(Of String)
   While myReader.Read()
    list.add(myreader.GetString(0))
End While
```

second:

```
  Dim listTransfer as list(Of String)
    Foreach ele as String in classname.list ' Replace classname '
      listTransfer.add(ele)  
    Next
```

Comment: that gets it done, but you're exposing a public field. encapsulate the field and expose a property getter instead - the property can be an `IEnumerable(Of String)`, since there is no need to expose `List` methods to other classes.

Comment: i think that i have explained it wrong, i have a class called db from this i want to send results to another class to be used. maybe it sound abstract but im new at this language and on PHP i have more practice to do the same.

Comment: No you didn't... you accesses the variable in the first class using. classname.variable

Comment: To be fair, the code in this answer doesn't convey the idea very well: `Dim list As New List(Of String)` should be at module level (in *class 1*, not in *the first method*), and should be `Public list As New List(Of String)` so that other classes can see it.